# How to navigate to different pages using a treeview in usercontrols WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

On my main window, I have a `Frame` which has a source of a landing page, on top of the frame is a user control which contains a `TreeView`, each node on the `TreeView` navigates to a different page.

When I click on each node I would like to change the source of the `Frame`.

How would I go about changing the `Source` of the `Frame` to the respective `Page` based on the `TreeView` node?

This is what I have tried thus far:

However, this only works if I place the `UserControl` on each `Page` and does not work if I place it on the `Frame` of the main window. When I tried the approach I want, I get a message saying that "Value is not set to an instance of an object"

This is the XAML of the user control:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeViewItem Header="applications"
                Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <TreeViewItem Name="newApplication"
                  Header="new applications"
                  MouseDoubleClick="NewApplication_MouseDoubleClick"></TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Name="approvedApplication"
                  Header="approved applications"
                  MouseDoubleClick="ApprovedApplication_MouseDoubleClick"></TreeViewItem>
  </TreeViewItem>
  <TreeViewItem Header="repair requests">
    <TreeViewItem Header="tester"></TreeViewItem>
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

This is the cs of the user control:

```
private void NewApplication_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  Uri uri = new Uri("/Views/oem_newApplications.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
  NavigationService ns = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
  ns.Navigate(uri);
}
```

This is the xaml of my MainWindow:

```
<Grid>
  <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Source="/Views/oem_main.xaml"/>

  <local:menuTree HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="584" Margin="0,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160"/>
</Grid>
```

I would like to place the user control on the `Frame` and use the `UserControl` to change the `Frame.Source`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `TreeView.SelectedItem` directly to `Frame.Source`. This solution uses the `FrameworkElement.Tag` property to store the `Page` URI. To make the binding work, you need to cast the `TreeView.SelectedItem` from `object` to `TreeViewItem`.

Alternatively you could introduce an attached property to hold the `Page` URIs.

In case the `TreeView` is part of a `UserControl` and not directly accessible, you should expose the `TreeView.SelectedItem` via a dedicated property (e.g. `SelectedPage`) and then bind `Frame.Source` to it:

**MenuTree.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MenuTree : UserControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedPage",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MenuTree),
    new PropertyMetadata("/landingPage.xaml"));

  public string SelectedPage
  {
    get { return (string) GetValue(MenuTree.SelectedPageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MenuTree.SelectedPageProperty, value); }
  }

  public MenuTree()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
  {
    this.SelectedPage = (e.NewValue as FrameworkElement)?.Tag as string;
  }
}
```

**MenuTree.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <TreeView x:Name="IndexTreeView" SelectedItemChanged="OnSelectedItemChanged" >
    <TreeViewItem Header="applications">
      <TreeViewItem Header="approved applications"
                    Tag="/ExamplePage.xaml" />
    </TreeViewItem>
  </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
  <Frame Source="{Binding ElementName=MenuTree, Path=SelectedPage}" />

  <local:menuTree x:Name="MenuTree" />
</Grid>
```

**ExamplePage.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="Main.ExamplePage">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Page 1"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how would I go about exposing the SelectedItem and bind it to the source? That is where I am stuck, Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I was about to add this information. Does this help? You have to create a `DependencyProperty` on your `UserControl`. I called it `SelectedPage`. Then bind `TreeView.SelectedItem` to it.

Comment: I've tried everything above with no errors, but Treeview cannot pick up SelectedItem , it somehow only pics up SelectedItemChanged

Comment: And if I change it to SelectedItemChanged the it does not pick up SelectedPage

Comment: This must work. Have you set the binding mode on the binding between `TreeView` and `UserControl` to `TwoWay`?

Comment: Yes I have. It's just that my treeview tag fails to recognize the "SelectedItem" property and only bring up "SelectedItemChanged "

Comment: Can you show me the "IsEditEnabledProperty" on the MainWindow?

Comment: Sorry. this was my bad. I didn't tested the code. It turned out that the `SelectedItem` property is read-only. We can't bind to it. Let me update the example code. Sorry...

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. You are right. We have to use the `SelectedItemChanged` event. I added an event handler to the `UserControl` that updates the `SelectedPage` property.

Comment: I fixed some naming issues and tested it. It works now.

Comment: I have one last question, upon load of the project I would like allow for my landing page to show up. As it stands OnLoad the source is blank. I assume that setting it on the Window Onloaded property will override the bind and not allow for change once the treeview item is clicked

Comment: Okay. I updated the answer. I changed the type of `SelectedPage` to `string` and adjusted the event handler and the binding on the `Frame.Source`. To set an initial `Page` just set the default value of the `SelectedPage` property to an URI like in the example.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again